C, Zbar library, two cameras scanning simultaneously
How can I scan QR codes using Zbar library using two web cameras?
  void *scanning_f(void *ptr)
  {
    const char *first_cam = "/dev/video0";
    const char *second_cam = "/dev/video2";

    zbar_processor_t *proc = zbar_processor_create(1);
    zbar_processor_set_config(proc, 0, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);
    zbar_processor_request_size(proc, 1024,  860);
    zbar_processor_init(proc, first_cam, 0);
    zbar_processor_set_data_handler(proc, handling, NULL);
    zbar_processor_set_visible(proc, 0);
    zbar_processor_set_active(proc, 1);
    
    zbar_processor_t *proc2 = zbar_processor_create(1);
    zbar_processor_set_config(proc2, 0, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);
    zbar_processor_request_size(proc2, 1024,  860);
    zbar_processor_init(proc2, second_cam, 0);
    zbar_processor_set_data_handler(proc2, handling, NULL);
    zbar_processor_set_visible(proc2, 0);
    zbar_processor_set_active(proc2, 1);
    
    while(1)
    {
        zbar_process_one(proc, 1000);
        zbar_process_one(proc2, 1000);
    }
}

This function

zbar_processor_set_active(proc, 1);

seems to lock the reading to the first activated camera. Even though both work (leds on).
